# Macro Button to transfer info from certain cells in one spreadsheet into a different spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I would like to be able to construct a macro that is easily able to transfer cell content from one spreadsheet to another. Let me elaborate in more detail: I currently have two spreadsheets open. See [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0yKv.png). The worksheet on the left works via a button macro that I made (not included in picture) and generates three different adjacent values. Thus every time I would click the button, a new output would be generated.

What I would like to be able to do is to transfer that information from the worksheet on the left to the worksheet on the right into columns G, H, and I respectively (by potentially clicking the button on the right worksheet) and then having it go to the next blank row to prepare for next round of generated values.

I'm having a bit of trouble constructing this (beginner). Could you offer some assistance?

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then
    If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) <> vbNullString Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Workbooks("Model.xlsx").Worksheets("Optimization").Range("C100").Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Workbooks("Model.xlsx").Worksheets("Optimization").Range("D100").Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Workbooks("Model.xlsx").Worksheets("Optimization").Range("E100").Value
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to S.O! Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code, take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider. [Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/)

Comment: Apologies. I've added my current code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Const RowToTakeInformation = 100
Const ColumnToTakeInformation = 3
Const ColToWriteIn = 7
Dim WBDesired As Workbook: Set WBDesired = Workbooks("Model.xlsx")
Dim WSDesired As Worksheet: Set WSDesired = Worksheets("Optimization")
'If everything is in the same WB, I don't see a valid reason why to set it
Dim RowToInsert As Long
Dim CounterColumnsToWrite As Long

    If WBDesired.Worksheets(WSDesired.Name).Cells(RowToTakeInformation, ColumnToTakeInformation).Value <> "" Then ' 1. If WBDesired.Worksheets(WSDesired.Name).Cells(RowToTakeInformation, ColumnToTakeInformation).Value <> ""
    'here I'm assuming it's a table or something like it that automatically recalculates when something is inserted in between
    RowToInsert = Cells(Rows.Count, ColToWriteIn).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    Rows(RowToInsert).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    For CounterColumnsToWrite = 0 To 2
    Cells(RowToInsert, ColToWriteIn + CounterColumnsToWrite).Value = WBDesired.Worksheets(WSDesired.Name).Cells(RowToTakeInformation, ColumnToTakeInformation + CounterColumnsToWrite)
    Next CounterColumnsToWrite
    End If ' 1. If WBDesired.Worksheets(WSDesired.Name).Cells(RowToTakeInformation, ColumnToTakeInformation).Value <> ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot! I seem to be getting an error on Set WSDesired = Worksheets("Optimization") Worksheets where it claims that subscript is out of range. I'm fairly certain that the worksheet name is correct.

Comment: Excel can't lie there, Have you checked spelling? If so, probably there are blank spaces among it.

Comment: you probably need `Set WSDesired = WBDesired.Worksheets("Optimization")`. So as to safely refer to `"Optimization"` worksheet of `"Model.xlsx"` file. While `Set WSDesired = Worksheets("Optimization")` would refer to `"Optimization"` worksheet of currently active workbook.  Then use it throughout the code!